# Reporting Services format for master detail

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, reportbuilder

How do I display Master Detail records on the report. I am trying to display in the following format.Could you please let me know how to do this? I appreciate any help.

My query returns in the following format.

```
Parent_id  Parent_name  Parent_value            Child_Column
    ----------------------------------------------------------
    1      test            20                   child row1
    1      test            20                   child row2
    1      test            20                   child row3
    2      test2           88                   child row4
    2      test2           88                   child row5
```

My report format should look like.

```
Record1:           test                     20

Child Rows:        Child Row1
                   Child Row2
--------------------------------------------------
Record2:           test2                    88

Child Rows:        Child Row1
                   Child Row2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll want to create a group on Parent_Name and Parent_Value in the designer.  You can then add the group header to display your desired output.  From there you'll want to add the necessary fields in the details section.  I know this sounds vague, but it's hard to explain without the IDE.  Hopefully you understand enough about SRS and SQL to get started with this suggestion.

Comment: I failed to add in my original post, you'll want to add a tablix (table) in order to setup the groupings.  This tablix should be your main data container for the report.

Comment: I placed tablix on the report. I placed Parent_name in one column and parent_value in another column and added a Group header. Where do I have to place the detail section?

Comment: Just confirming... you created a group based on the Parent_Name and Parent_Value right?  Then in that group head (in the designer) you added the Parent_name and Parent_value columns?

Comment: Yes. I did. What is Group By? I selected Parent_Id as Group_by. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Is there anyway I can display Record1, Record2 etc for Parent records? Is it possible to display child rows in bulled format without table row borders?

Comment: Please do not take this the wrong way, but StackOverflow is not a site to get "how-to" instructions, but it's a site for programming questions, such as assistance with understanding a concept for a design pattern for example.  There are plenty other web sites that can assist with "how-to" for SSRS.